# Redirection to a php page via html href tag

Tags: php, html, redirect

i have this button which is on one page and when user clicks on it, it is supposed to redirect to the page mentioned.

```
<div id="backicon"><a href="<?php PSF::urlFor('default_home');?>"><img src="com/resources/images/backicon.png"></a></div>
```

href is supposed to work with the php and it should redirect to the `default_home` page, but nothing happens on click. i believe i am missing a thing or two about php code inside html tag?
i also tried

```
<a href="' . PSF::urlFor('default') . '">Back</a>
```

but of no use, any help?

Comment: Inspect the link in your browser and see if the link is there / code is correct.

Comment: Use echo in your <a> tag  <a href="<?php  echo PSF::urlFor('default_home');?>">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This returns the PSF:urlFor, but doesn't echo it. Try it like so:

```
<div id="backicon"><a href="<?php echo PSF::urlFor('default_home');?>"><img src="com/resources/images/backicon.png"></a></div>
```